# How can I extract data points from a black and white image?

Tags: graphics, import, image-processing

Consider the following graph [(source)](http://avspublications.org/jvsta/resource/1/jvtad6/v8/i4/p3260_s1?isAuthorized=no):

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Is there any way to extract the data points from this image in a semi-automatic way? I have seen, and tried the methods suggested in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1524/recovering-data-points-from-an-image), but they did not work, as most of the approaches there utilize color contrast to extract the data; I couldn't get `barChartDigitizer` to work, either.

Comment: See this question too, which was also mentioned in the comments on the one you linked to http://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/1061/581

Comment: It is not Mathematica-related, but [WebPlotDigitizer](http://arohatgi.info/WebPlotDigitizer/) is a great web tool to extract published data from graph images.

Comment: can you explain how `barChartDigitizer` failed?

Comment: ...but in any case I like @kguler's answer: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1524/recovering-data-points-from-an-image/1525#1525 though not sure why it would not have worked for this picture??

Comment: ok just tried it. forgot that it only stores y values. Should be easy to extend to lines. This is actually my code from a couple of years ago that I put on wildebeest.net. I'll update for lines.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch Why don't you suggest a working version as an answer? I tried following the links to the full description, but that site seems to be down.

Comment: Yeah stopped the site when I returned to Australia. I'm going to make a revised version today and will post the answer when done.

Comment: Here is a solution that might work for you: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/167483/55694

Comment: If not Mathematica, you may try [PlotDigitizer.com](https://plotdigitizer.com/). It has a [free online app](https://plotdigitizer.com/app) that can extract data from graph images.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

### Another update

Not sure when this was introduced, but copying the demo figure provided above from your browser window to Mathematica using copy and paste results in each pixel being defined by 4 values instead of usual three RGB values. I suppose the fourth is an alpha channel used for opacity. This is not the case if you `Import` using the image link.

Getting the image using copy and paste also provides the image with options that differ by version. In 11.3 the options are `{ColorSpace -> "RGB", Interleaving -> True}`, whereas in 13.3.1 the options are `{ColorSpace -> "RGB", ImageResolution -> {96., 96.}, ImageSize -> {353.438, Automatic}, Interleaving -> True}`. This and the added alpha channel causes problems with the `ImageTrim` function and everything following it. It explains the issue Kvothe reported in the comments below.

The workaround is either importing the image using its link or getting rid of the alpha layer and the `ImageResolution` option using something like:

```
im2 = Image[ImageData[im][[All, All, ;; 3]], 
            {ColorSpace -> "RGB", Interleaving -> True}
      ]
```

where `im` is assigned to the copy-and-pasted figure.

For me, this makes it work again.

### UPDATE: Added a few workarounds for bugs / features introduced in Mathematica v10 or later.

Main issue involved `LocatorPane` whose `Appearance` option no longer correctly handles more than one `Graphics` object [CASE:4984027]. This bug was introduced somewhere after v11.3 and is present in v.13.1.  Additional issues concerned the scaling of the graphics used in the various panels, which was incorrect. Perhaps a different default was introduced somewhere after v9 where the code worked as intended.

---

---

**Original text**

Here the contours of a method to do this half-automatic selection you are looking for. It is heavily based on an example on the `ImageCorrelate` doc page of Waldo fame. First, you interactively select an example of the plot marker you want to look for:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhPr9.png"];

pt = {ImageDimensions[img]/4, ImageDimensions[img]/2};
LocatorPane[
 Dynamic[pt],
 Dynamic[
  Show[
   img,
   Graphics[
    {
     EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[], Rectangle @@ pt
     }
    ]
   ]
  ], Appearance -> Graphics[{Red, AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[{0, 0}]}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then you use Mathematica v8's image processing tools to find similar structures:

```
res =
  ComponentMeasurements[
   MorphologicalComponents[
    ColorNegate[
     Binarize[
      ImageCorrelate[
       img,
       ImageTrim[img, pt],
       NormalizedSquaredEuclideanDistance
       ], 0.18
      ]
     ]
    ], {"Centroid", "Area"}, #2 > 1 & (*use only the larger hits*)
   ];
```

The coordinates are now in `res`. I'll show them below. Many are correct, sometimes you get some spurious hits and misses. It depends on the `Binarize` threshold value and the "Area" size chosen in `ComponentMeasurements` third argument.

```
Show[img, Graphics[{Green, Circle[#, 5] & /@ res[[All, 2, 1]]}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

**EDIT:** Here a more complete application. It is not robust as it is (no error handling at all), but nevertheless already quite useful.

The function `getMarkers` is called with an image as argument and the name of a variable in which the final markers are returned:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You get the app with tabs that represent processing stages:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In the first tab you define the axes by dragging the colored dots to the locations on the x and y axis with the highest known value and to the origin of the plot. Here, you also enter the values for the bottom left and top right corners of the rectangle that they define:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In the next tab you then indicate the marker you want to have detected:
[image: Mathematica graphics]

The detection results are presented in the next tab and you can drag a slider to increase or decrease the number of results:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can manually adjust the detected markers in the next tab. Markers can be dragged, removed (alt-click an existing marker) and added (alt-click on an empty spot). Actually, this is so easy to do that I would be tempted to say that I could do without the marker-detection  phase.

The end result can be seen in the Results tab. If something is wrong you can go back to an earlier tab:
[image: Mathematica graphics].

The data plotted in the Results tab is also copied in the variable passed to the function, test in this example.

```
test

(*
==> {{400.5159959, 0.007353847123}, {450.3095975, 
  0.005511544915}, {499.8452012, 0.004129136525}, {550.9287926, 
  0.002664992936}, {600.4643963, 0.001702431875}, {653.869969, 
  0.000764540446}, {685.6037152, 0.0002398789942}, {764.7123323, 
  0.0002481309886}, {801.7027864, 0.0001989932135}}
*)
```

The code:

```
findMarkers[img_, pt_, thres_, minArea_] :=
  ComponentMeasurements[
    MorphologicalComponents[
     ColorNegate[
      Binarize[
       ImageCorrelate[img, ImageTrim[img, pt],
        NormalizedSquaredEuclideanDistance
        ], thres]
      ]
     ],
    {"Centroid", "Area"},
    #2 > minArea &
    ][[All, 2, 1]];

SetAttributes[getMarkers, HoldRest];
getMarkers[img_, resMarkers_] :=
 DynamicModule[
  {
   pt = {ImageDimensions[img]/4, ImageDimensions[img]/2},
   axisDefinePane, defineMarkerPane, findMarkerPane, editMarkersPane, 
   finalResultPane, xAxisBegin, xAxisEnd, yAxisBegin, yAxisEnd, 
   myMarkers, myTransform, 
   xoy = {{1/2, 1/8} ImageDimensions[img], {1/8, 1/8} ImageDimensions[
       img], {1/8, 1/2} ImageDimensions[img]}},
  axisDefinePane =
   Grid[
    {
     {
      LocatorPane[
       Dynamic[xoy],
       Dynamic[
        Show[
         img,
         Graphics[{Line[xoy]}],
         ImageSize -> ImageDimensions[img]
         ]
        ],
       Appearance ->
        {
         Graphics[{AbsolutePointSize[5], Red, Point[{0, 0}]}],
         Graphics[{AbsolutePointSize[5], Green, Point[{0, 0}]}],
         Graphics[{AbsolutePointSize[5], Blue, Point[{0, 0}]}]
         }
       ]
      },
     {Row[{"x(1): ", 
        InputField[Dynamic[xAxisBegin], Number, FieldSize -> Tiny], 
        " x(2): ", 
        InputField[Dynamic[xAxisEnd], Number, 
         FieldSize -> Tiny]}]}, {Row[{"y(1): ", 
        InputField[Dynamic[yAxisBegin], Number, FieldSize -> Tiny], 
        " y(2): ", 
        InputField[Dynamic[yAxisEnd], Number, 
         FieldSize -> Tiny]}]}}];
  
  defineMarkerPane =
   LocatorPane[
    Dynamic[pt],
    Dynamic[
     Show[
      img,
      Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[], Rectangle @@ pt}],
      ImageSize -> ImageDimensions[img]
      ]
     ],
    Appearance -> Style["\[FilledSmallCircle]", Red]
    ];
  
  findMarkerPane =
   Manipulate[
    Show[
     img,
     Graphics[{Red, 
       Circle[#, 5] & /@ (myMarkers = findMarkers[img, pt, t, 1.05])}],
     ImageSize -> ImageDimensions[img]
     ],
    {{t, 0.2, "Threshold"}, 0, 1},
    TrackedSymbols -> {t},
    ControlPlacement -> Bottom
    ];
  
  editMarkersPane =
   LocatorPane[
    Dynamic[myMarkers],
    img,
    Appearance -> 
     Graphics[{Red, Circle[{0, 0}, 1]}, ImageSize -> 10],
    LocatorAutoCreate -> True
    ];
  
  finalResultPane =
   Dynamic[
    myTransform = 
     FindGeometricTransform[{{xAxisEnd, yAxisBegin}, {xAxisBegin, 
          yAxisBegin}, {xAxisBegin, yAxisEnd}}, xoy][[2]] // Quiet;
    ListLinePlot[resMarkers = myTransform /@ Sort[myMarkers], 
     Frame -> True, Mesh -> All, ImageSize -> ImageDimensions[img]],
    TrackedSymbols -> {myMarkers, xoy, xAxisEnd, yAxisBegin, 
      xAxisBegin, yAxisBegin, xAxisBegin, yAxisEnd}
    ];
  
  TabView[
   {
    "Define axes" -> axisDefinePane,
    "Define marker" -> defineMarkerPane,
    "Find Markers" -> findMarkerPane,
    "Edit Markers" -> editMarkersPane,
    "Results" -> finalResultPane
    }
   ]
  ]
```

Comment: This looks fantastic. I'll try it out when I get to work tomorrow.

Comment: This is great. The one thing I needed to do was map the coordinates from the image system to the axis system. I used `{o, y, x} = {{31., 3.}, {32., 197.}, {357.328, 3.}}`, and `trans = FindGeometricTransform[{{400, 2.1}, {400, 2.7},{900, 2.1}}, {o, y, x}][[2]]`. Then `trans@res[[All, 2, 1]]`.

Comment: @EliLansey Yeah, that's the way to go. Additionally, you could use `res` in a `LocaterPane` to manually adjust the automatically found settings and add points the method did not find.

Comment: @EliLansey See update. Wrapped it into a more complete app.

Comment: Wow! That's absolutely terrific! Wish I had another +1.

Comment: This is great, Sjoerd!

Comment: @EliLansey Small update. The last panel had some idle activity and I got rid of that, I localized a few forgotten variables and improved naming and did some miscellaneous clean-up.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries One thought for a useful option: Lock axes. Since many plots have strictly rectangular axes (i.e. no need to do a skew/shear transform), it might give more accurate results if the x-y axis selector could be locked at 90deg.

Comment: @EliLansey Plenty of ideas for future improvements: define axes if the axes have a break in them (so, pick two points on each axes), log plots, ability to select multiply plot markers etc. etc. But the post is already long as it is, and the site is not really meant for application development. We should use GitHub or SourceForge for that.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries True. Another nifty thing would be to extract lines or markers.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I'm wondering if there were any developments on GitHub or SourceForge? I'm running into an error "The distance function NormalizedSquaredEuclideanDistance is not defined for constant kernels" when I try it on an image smaller than the full sized image provided. IE this works: http://i.stack.imgur.com/hhPr9.png but this errors: http://imgur.com/MvhO7hD .  I don't follow the code so I can't begin to make a contribution.  Also, an option to just have the 'edit markers field' IE manually add points instead of detection and alteration then manually add points would be great.

Comment: @AndrewStewart Your figure works for me without a hitch. How did you use it in the call to the function? As to adding points: you can just skip the recognition tab and add points using Alt-click in the edit markers tab. Be sure, though, to define the axes in the first tab.

Comment: Fantastic answer! One of the best on this site!

Comment: @Adrian Glad you like it.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries
This works great in 10.0, but in version 10.4, I get the same error mentioned by Andrew Stewart (problems with the NormalizedSquaredEuclideanDistance). I've had a few cracks at fixing it. But i am getting no where. Otherwise, this is awesome in terms of functionality and in terms of learning from someone many levels above in skillz. Thank you!

Comment: @xsk8rat It works OK on my $Version "10.4.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (April 11, 2016)"

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Thank you for the feedback. I will try modifying the image. That seems to have worked for Andrew Stewart as he notes above. Again thanks for the app! Cheers!

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries  Success! I imported the graph from a PNG file, rather than pasting from Word for windows.(???). It was a little smaller in size - which may only be a coincidence. But the data was easily extracted. Again: Awesome!

Comment: I had trouble with the first step (before the edit ) moving both locators. I removed the `Appearance -> Graphics[{Red, AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[{0, 0}]}` option and now I can move both points. I guess the problem might have been related to the `Point[{0, 0}]` in that option. I seem to have the same issue in the code in  the edit section. Maybe it is just me that does not understand how to move both points.

Comment: @userrandrand It is ten year old code and several things changed in the later Mathematica versions. The issue you reported wasn't there in v11, but I see it happening in v13. But there are other issues too. If I have time I'll try to fix them.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries ok. I left the comment there in case anyone else wanted to try. I should have mentioned that in my comment. It does look rather nice.

Comment: @userrandrand I updated the code. Should work now again.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries pretty quick update. I checked and it works nicely. It's quite convenient. I might use that format for other stuff in the future if I figure out the details of how it works. I am in the process of checking a code that finds the scales and points automatically by reading the text in the image.  I use `ImageLines` to separate the plot into [plot region, x labels, y labels, rest] and use 'TextRecognize` after some preprocessing to recognize the text. I might use this format for checking intermediate steps and adjusting images.

Comment: I am getting "ImageCorrelate::klcst: The distance function NormalizedSquaredEuclideanDistance is not defined for constant kernels." when going to the Find Markers tab. Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: @Kvothe See update in the beginning of the answer. This was a quite puzzling bug, presumably caused by a change in the copy and paste behavior of Mathematica.

Answer (score 18):

As per comments above, `barChartDigitizer` can be extended to {x,y} scatter plots.

```
scatterPlotDigitizer[g_Image] := 
 DynamicModule[{ymin, yminValue = 0., ymax, ymaxValue = 1., xmin, 
   xminValue = 0., xmax, xmaxValue = 1., pt = {0, 0}, data = {}, 
   img = ImageDimensions[g], output},

  Deploy@Column[{
     Row[{
       Grid[{
         {Button["Y Axis Min", ymin = pt[[2]]], 
          Button["Y Axis Max", ymax = pt[[2]]]},
         {InputField[Dynamic[yminValue], Number, ImageSize -> 70], 
          InputField[Dynamic[ymaxValue], Number, ImageSize -> 70]},
         {Button["X Axis Min", xmin = pt[[1]]], 
          Button["X Axis Max", xmax = pt[[1]]]},
         {InputField[Dynamic[xminValue], Number, ImageSize -> 70], 
          InputField[Dynamic[xmaxValue], Number, ImageSize -> 70]}
         }],
       Column[{Button["Add point", AppendTo[data, pt]],
         Button["Remove Last", data = Quiet@Check[Most@data, {}]]}],
       Column[{Button["Start Over", data = {}],
         Button["Print Output", 
          output = 
           Transpose[{Rescale[#, {xmin, xmax}, {xminValue, 
                 xmaxValue}] & /@ data[[All, 1]], 
             Rescale[#, {ymin, ymax}, {yminValue, ymaxValue}] & /@ 
              data[[All, 2]]}]; 
          Print@Column[{ListPlot[output, ImageSize -> 400, 
              PlotRange -> {{xminValue, xmaxValue}, {yminValue, 
                 ymaxValue}}], output}], 
          Enabled -> Dynamic[data =!= {}]]}]
       }],
     Row[{
       Graphics[{Inset[
          Image[g, ImageSize -> img]], {Tooltip[Locator[Dynamic[pt]], 
           Dynamic[pt]]}},
        ImageSize -> img, PlotRange -> 1, 
        AspectRatio -> img[[2]]/img[[1]]]}]
     }]
  ]
```

The steps to using this function are:

1. Copy the image of the plot you want to digitize and paste it as an argument to scatterPlotDigitizer.
2. Enter the minimum and maximum y axis values in the input fields.
3. Enter the minimum and maximum x axis values in the input fields.
4. Place the locator on the y minimum and click "Y Axis Min."
5. Place the locator on the y maximum and click "Y Axis Max."
6. Place the locator on the x minimum and click "X Axis Min."
7. Place the locator on the x maximum and click "X Axis Max."
8. Then place the locator over a point and click "Add point."
9. When you're done click "Print Output."

when applied to your plot you get:

```
data4 = {{401.5337423312884`, 
    0.0159090909090909`}, {450.6134969325154`, 
    0.013181818181818173`}, {501.2269938650307`, 
    0.010757575757575744`}, {548.7730061349694`, 
    0.007272727272727254`}, {600.920245398773`, 
    0.00439393939393937`}, {654.601226993865`, 
    0.0024242424242423948`}, {702.1472392638036`, 
    0.0012121212121211783`}, {800.3067484662575`, \
-0.0003030303030303362`}};

data5 = {{403.0674846625767`, 
    0.007272727272727247`}, {452.14723926380367`, 
    0.005454545454545431`}, {502.760736196319`, 
    0.003939393939393916`}, {551.840490797546`, 
    0.002575757575757554`}, {600.920245398773`, 
    0.0015151515151514937`}, {654.601226993865`, 
    0.0007575757575757416`}, {703.680981595092`, 
    0.00030303030303028763`}};

data6 = {{401.5337423312884`, 
    0.005303030303030292`}, {452.14723926380367`, 
    0.003181818181818171`}, {499.69325153374234`, 
    0.001818181818181809`}, {550.3067484662577`, 
    0.0007575757575757486`}, {602.4539877300613`, 
    0.0001515151515151386`}};

p2 = ListLinePlot[{data5, data4, data6},
  Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> {{"Extinction\ncoefficient (k)", 
     None}, {"Wavelength (nm)", None}},
  FrameTicks -> {{{0.01, 0.02}, 
     None}, {{400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900}, None}},
  FrameTicksStyle -> 
   Directive[FontFamily -> "Helevetica", 16, Black, Bold],
  ImageSize -> 400,
  ImagePadding -> {{90, 20}, {50, 1}},
  LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helevetica", 16, Black, Bold],
  PlotRange -> {{xminValue, xmaxValue}, {0, 0.0225}},
  PlotMarkers -> {
    {Graphics[{EdgeForm[Directive[Thick, Thick]], Black, 
       Disk[{0, 0}, 1]}], 
     0.05}, {Graphics[{EdgeForm[Directive[Thick, Thick]], White, 
       Disk[{0, 0}, 1]}], 
     0.05}, {Graphics[{EdgeForm[Directive[Thick, Thick]], White, 
       Polygon[{{0, 0}, {0.5, 0.707}, {1, 0}}]}], 0.05}
    },
  PlotStyle -> Black]
```

and

```
data1 = {{401.5337423312883`, 
    2.4784615384615387`}, {449.07975460122697`, 
    2.3984615384615386`}, {499.6932515337423`, 
    2.3400000000000003`}, {550.3067484662575`, 
    2.293846153846154`}, {599.3865030674846`, 
    2.263076923076923`}, {651.5337423312883`, 
    2.241538461538462`}, {700.6134969325153`, 
    2.2292307692307696`}, {751.2269938650306`, 
    2.216923076923077`}, {800.3067484662577`, 
    2.210769230769231`}, {900.`, 2.201538461538462`}};

data2 = {{401.5337423312884`, 
    2.5237113402061855`}, {449.079754601227`, 
    2.4556701030927837`}, {501.2269938650307`, 
    2.4`}, {548.7730061349694`, 
    2.3597938144329897`}, {599.3865030674847`, 
    2.3288659793814435`}, {651.5337423312883`, 
    2.304123711340206`}, {700.6134969325153`, 
    2.288659793814433`}, {749.6932515337423`, 
    2.2731958762886597`}, {798.7730061349694`, 
    2.260824742268041`}, {900.`, 2.245360824742268`}};

data3 = {{400.`, 2.4494845360824744`}, {449.0797546012271`, 
    2.369072164948454`}, {498.1595092024541`, 
    2.316494845360825`}, {548.7730061349694`, 
    2.276288659793815`}, {599.3865030674847`, 
    2.239175257731959`}, {651.5337423312884`, 
    2.2144329896907218`}, {699.079754601227`, 
    2.205154639175258`}, {749.6932515337423`, 
    2.1958762886597936`}, {800.3067484662577`, 
    2.1896907216494843`}, {898.4662576687116`, 2.183505154639175`}};

p1 = ListLinePlot[{data1, data2, data3},
  Epilog -> {Inset[
     Style["Starting material TiO:\nIonised oxygen", 
      FontFamily -> "Helevetica", 14, Black, Bold], 
     ImageScaled[{0.55, .82}], {Left, Top}]},
  Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> {{"Refractive\nIndex (n)", None}, {None, None}},
  FrameTicks -> {{{2.1, 2.3, 2.5, 2.7}, None}, {None, None}},
  FrameTicksStyle -> 
   Directive[FontFamily -> "Helevetica", 16, Black, Bold],
  ImageSize -> 400,
  ImagePadding -> {{90, 20}, {7, 10}},
  LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helevetica", 16, Black, Bold],
  PlotRange -> {{xminValue, xmaxValue}, {yminValue, ymaxValue}},
  PlotMarkers -> {
    {Graphics[{EdgeForm[Directive[Thick, Thick]], Black, 
       Disk[{0, 0}, 1]}], 
     0.05}, {Graphics[{EdgeForm[Directive[Thick, Thick]], White, 
       Disk[{0, 0}, 1]}], 
     0.05}, {Graphics[{EdgeForm[Directive[Thick, Thick]], White, 
       Polygon[{{0, 0}, {0.5, 0.707}, {1, 0}}]}], 0.05}
    },
  PlotStyle -> Black]
```

which can be combined to give:

```
Grid[{{p1}, {p2}}, Spacings -> 0]
```

[image]

I have used `ListLinePlot` to join the dots simply to show this working but your chart appears to have **fitted lines (most notable in the bottom chart)** ...which you could add. I haven't bothered to change the tick lengths or adding the arrows, aspect ratio etc.

This is of course is a time consuming way of extracting points but it works. Also if the image is distorted you can probably fix this using some of the corrective measures described by others in the Q&A that you linked to.

Comment: I am not sure what I'm doing wrong here, but I set the origin values (clicking the buttons after entering the values), then center the locator over each point, and click "Add point." When I've done that for each point, I click "Print Output," but it spits out a List of {Indeterminate,Indeterminate}.

Comment: just added the steps -- which I should have written in the first place.

Comment: I like this for things where a more automated approach won't work

Answer (score 7):

For simple cases, where a manual method is enough, I do the following:

[image: image= ;]

Then, with the help of get coordinates (from the context menu):

```
imageCut = ImageTrim[image, {{96, 222}, {421, 417}}]
```

Followed by:

```
range = {{400, 900}, {2.1, 2.7}};
Graphics[Inset[imageCut, Scaled[{0, 0}], {0, 0}, Scaled[{1, 1}]], 
 PlotRange -> range, AspectRatio -> ImageAspectRatio[imageCut], 
 ImageSize -> 400, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
 PlotRangePadding -> 0]
```

[image]

And then you can easily use the Get Coordinates

I know this I not perfect, neither complete. The following post talks a little more on the subject [Link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1524/recovering-data-points-from-an-image#comment3892_1524).

Comment: This is the same issue as with vucko's answer. I'd prefer not to do it manually.

Comment: @EliLansey I agree with you, but sometime not even the best software to find waldo can be more intelligent than the human analysis (not the case, but it depends to what limit you want to go). I think that, starting from my basis, and adding locators to define a search area/envelope (again, by hand), plus a statistical analysis on the points location existing inside the envelope can do the trick (unless you really want hands off technology, which with the number of artifacts your graphic has, clearly would be beyond my skills).

Answer (score 5):

If you have to extract the data of only this plot, then you can use Graphics->Drawing Tools and use Get Coordinates. You can then click on all the points of interest in the figure to mark the coordinates and <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy marked coordinates to the clipboard.

Comment: This is a more general question. This is one example dataset. In principle, I'd like to do this for others, as well.

Comment: Also, the manual approach will be highly sensitive to manual shakiness when getting coordinates.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried...

```
img = "image file";
lines = ImageLines[EdgeDetect[img, 13], .18];
Show[img, Graphics[{Thick, Red, Line /@ lines}]]
```

Comment: Yes, doesn't work.