# Importing data from Plot

Tags: plotting, import, data-acquisition

Is it somehow possible to extract the datapoints from a plot imported from an image? i know it is possible to do that from a plot you made in the current session of mathematica, but i'm not sure if there is a way to do this by just importing the image and somehow helping mathematica to recognize the exis and the plot scales. unitl now I was just using the online app at http://arohatgi.info/WebPlotDigitizer/app/?, but that's not optimal

Comment: What's the image format?

Comment: These should help: [3831](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3831/how-can-i-extract-data-points-from-a-black-and-white-image); [1524](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1524/recovering-data-points-from-an-image); [20274](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20274/extract-data-from-plots-in-papers-including-error-bars); [105383](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/105383/extract-data-from-a-graph-image).

Comment: jpg, png, pdf are the ones i use most, pdf first

Comment: 20274 sounds very helpfull!