# How do I find the coordinates of points in this image?

Tags: image-processing

I have never used image processing with Mathematica.  I need to get the coordinates of the red points from this image I made in Illustrator.  Is there a way to get Mathematica to read or detect the x-y coordinates?

[image]

Comment: Of course, you need a coordinate system... where is the origin, for instance?

Comment: Anywhere can be the origin.  I will shift and scale the numbers as need be!

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3831/how-can-i-extract-data-points-from-a-black-and-white-image/3832#3832) question and its answers can be of help for you. I guess with a bit of work you can create a solution for your problem.

Comment: After applying `Binarize[]` to the OP's image, the question is now equivalent to the one linked by @partial81; unless I see a reason why this is not a dupe, I'm leaning towards closing this.

Comment: Wouldn't `PixelValuePositions[i, Red, .2]` be quicker though?

Comment: I agree @0x4A4D. If QuantumDot cannot tell us why his question needs another solution, I would close it too.

Comment: @cormullion you should post this as an answer

Comment: No, really; why are people not posting answers to the other question that was previously linked?

Comment: Quick question: if it's made in Illustrator, can't you export to EPS and extract the points using string processing? Does it have to be done with image techniques?

Comment: @Jens I was hoping to figure out how to do that -- but I couldn't, so doing it this way was my last-ditch try.

Comment: whether it is possible in the same way to get the coordinates of points on the curve?

Comment: This is not Mathematica, but I prefer [PlotDigitizer.com](https://plotdigitizer.com). It is a GUI solution and can extract data from several types of graphs, including XY. You check out its [free online app](https://plotdigitizer.com/app).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A solution for *Mathematica* version 9:

```
image = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0Dqo.png"]
pts = PixelValuePositions[image, Red, .2];
ListPlot[pts, 
 PlotStyle -> Darker@Orange, 
 PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, .05}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1500}, {0, 800}}, 
 ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image: listplot of points]

Comment: Very nice solution! Fortunately the question was not closed ;-) I did not know the `PixelValuePositions` so far (seems to be new in MMA 9).

Comment: Are there really two thousand points in the original image (length of `pts` above)?

Comment: `PixelValuePositions[Thinning@ColorNegate@ImageCrop@Binarize@image, 1]` perhaps.

Comment: Or `thinned = DeleteDuplicates[pts, EuclideanDistance[#1, #2] < 2 &]` to keep it as data...?

Comment: @cormullion I agree, should distance *2* not exclude certain original dot.

Comment: I already gave a +1, but `PixelValuePositions` proved useful, elsewhere.

Comment: I get a nice clustering using this: `pts = Mean /@ Gather[pts, EuclideanDistance[#1, #2] < 4 &];`

Answer (score 8):

The question leaves open what a "point" is, as opposed to a pixel.

### Attempt at points

If points overlap in the image, it is beyond my skill to separate them.  Others here have far more experience in image processing and may be able to suggest things, within limits.
If the points are separated,
then here's a rough stab at finding them:

```
MorphologicalComponents[Binarize[img, {0.29, 0.6}], 0.68] // Colorize
```

[image: MorphologicalComponents]

```
(rules = ArrayRules[MorphologicalComponents[Binarize[img, {0.29, 0.6}], 0.68]];
  points = Mean /@ Map[First, GatherBy[rules, Last], {2}];) // Timing
Length[points]
```

> ```
> {0.072981, Null}
> 195
> ```

The `points` are image coordinates; we should convert them to graphics coordinates before plotting:

```
ListPlot[{#[[2]], Last@ImageDimensions[img] - #[[1]]} & /@ points, 
 PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 2}, 
 PlotRange -> Transpose[{{0, 0}, ImageDimensions[img]}], 
 PlotRangePadding -> 50, AxesOrigin -> {0, -50}]
```

[image: Point plot]

### Pixels

The same method is an efficient way to get the pixels (especially if you do not have v9 and `PixelValuePositions` to use).

```
(rules = ArrayRules[MorphologicalComponents[Binarize[img, {0.29, 0.6}], 0.68]];
  pixelCoords = SparseArray[rules]["NonzeroPositions"];) // Timing
Length@pixelCoords
```

> ```
> {0.070562, Null}
> 2629
> ```

```
ListPlot[{#[[2]], Last@ImageDimensions[img] - #[[1]]} & /@ pixelCoords,
 PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 0.25}, 
 PlotRange -> Transpose[{{0, 0}, ImageDimensions[img]}], 
 PlotRangePadding -> 50, AxesOrigin -> {0, -50}]
```

[image: Pixel plot]

---

This way is nearly as fast and gives the same result as above:

```
pixelCoords = Position[ImageData@Binarize[img, {0.29, 0.6}], 1]; // Timing
Length@pixelCoords
```

> ```
> {0.108690, Null}
> 2629
> ```

Comment: Good work, +1. Although we're probably all just exploring for fun, since the OP's Illustrator file likely contains the actual coordinate pairs of every point

Comment: @cormullion Yes, processing images is an attractive pastime, but it's not something I am very good at yet.

Answer (score 4):

Using relatively simple functions:

```
c = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0Dqo.png"] ;
a = Rasterize[c];
reds = Cases[Union[Flatten[a[[1, 1]], 1]], {r_ /; r > 200, g_ /; g < 50, b_ /; b < 50}];
Row[{First[Timing[b = Map[Position[a[[1, 1]], #] &, reds]]], " seconds"}]
```

> 13.073 seconds

```
ListPlot[Reverse /@ Flatten[b, 1], PlotStyle -> Red, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another way without *Mathematica* version 9 `PixelValuePositions`

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0Dqo.png"];
pix = Round[ImageData[img, DataReversed -> True]];
ListPlot[Reverse /@ Position[pix, {1, 0, 0}], AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]