# How to extract data points from an image of a log log plot?

Tags: plotting, graphics, image-processing

I have a picture of a log-log plot, taken from a paper and I want to extract the data points so I will be able to plot them again along with results of my own solution. I would appreciate your help. This picture contains three sets of data, I only need to extract the data associated with DCB legend (shown by circles)
:[image]

Comment: Oh my! And those poor guys working days and nights to get those measurements!:)

Comment: Please write down what you've tried.Hint: there are similar questions on this site: search for them!

Comment: @belisarius Thank for your response. I am using this experimental measurements as a verification to my model and of course I will cite their work.

Comment: Just in case it wasn't clear, I was joking. There are zillions of good (and ethical) reasons to do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [(3831)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3831/121).  Related:  [(1524)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1524/121), [(26356)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26356/121),
[(44355)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/44355/121)

Comment: I published a function here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44355/how-to-make-a-curve-selectable-from-a-scaned-image-and-convert-it-to-a-list-of-c/44358#44358 that makes exactly what you need. Have fun!