# Using a LocatorPane

Tags: programming, locator

I have a network of a power grid where the edge are the power lines and the vertices are loads or generators. I was wondering how I can import an image into *Mathematica* to derive some sort of coordinate system to calculate some topological properties that are related to distance and position using Monte Carlo Cooling methods and other methods of this sort. The code below is giving me back errors that are shown below.

```
im = Import["C:\Research\Pictures\FloridaPowerGrid.jpg"];
Module[{picturesize, i, bigger, imagesizes}, 
  picturesize = {1038, 1386};
  values = {};
  i = 1;
  imagesizes = ImageDimensions[im]; bigger = 1;
  DynamicModule[{pt = {0, 0}},
   If[imagesizes[[1]] < imagesizes[[2]], bigger = 2];
   TableForm@{
    Button["Record!", AppendTo[values, {i, pt}]; i++;], 
    LocatorPane[Dynamic@pt, 
      Dynamic @ Graphics[
        Join[
          {Inset[im, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {1, 1}]}, 
          Flatten[{Blue, Disk[#[[2]], .01], White, Text[#[[1]], #[[2]]]} & /@ values]], 
        PlotRange -> 
          {{0, imagesizes[[1]]/imagesizes[[bigger]]}, 
          {0, imagesizes[[2]]/imagesizes[[bigger]]}}, 
        ImageSize -> picturesize]], 
    Dynamic[N @ pt], 
    Dynamic[MatrixForm@values]}]]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: the short answer is yes but the long answer is complicated and requires more info. Are you wanting to use locators to get coords of points on the image? If so this post might offer some ideas: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3831/how-can-i-extract-data-points-from-a-black-and-white-image

Comment: The gist of my code is trying to set up a coordinate system to get relative distances for a power grid system.

http://pastebin.com/sMJWJNfP

Comment: I put the pastebin to my code above for help to see if the code will suffice for my needs

Comment: This is what I get as my error message. http://imgur.com/V3eQlib

Comment: It is not a good idea to have `Module` values that you intend to use dynamically. Get rid of Module and bring everything into your dynamic module and try again

Comment: ...and replace `TableForm` with `Column` and not sure that your `pt` is used correctly either but have no time now to investigate

Comment: Using `MatrixForm` is probably not a good idea either. Try replacing it with `Grid`.

Comment: How about uploading the picture `FloridaPowerGrid`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with importing the picture. It had to be.jpg.jpg since I saved it as FloridaPowerGrid.jpg but it automatically adds .jpg when saved. I appreciate all the help and effort from this community.