# extract data from a graph image

Tags: image-processing, data-acquisition

How do I convert the following image graph into data (if possible into function)?

[image]

I checked [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1524/recovering-data-points-from-an-image) and found that my problem is grid and plot have same color.

Comment: what about: [3831](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3831/5478)

Comment: @Kuba thank you i'll check it out.

Comment: Here is a solution that might work for you: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/167483/55694

Comment: Maybe you should try [plotdigitizer](https://plotdigitizer.com/). You can eliminate the grid lines by masking the curve.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the problem is only to remove the grid, that's relatively easy. You just remove everything *but* the grid, then take the difference.

You can use `Closing` with a rectangular structuring element to remove everything but the horizontal / vertical grid lines, like this:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkvSR.png"];    
hFilter = Closing[img, BoxMatrix[{10, 0}]];
vFilter = Closing[img, BoxMatrix[{0, 10}]];
```

then take the pixel-wise min to get the full grid:

```
grid = ImageApply[Min, {hFilter, vFilter}];
```

[image]

Then simply binarize the difference:

```
Binarize[ImageDifference[img, grid]]
```

[image]

(From here, you should be able to use code from the answers already linked.)