# How to determine distance of periodic features in measured dataset

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have a list of x- and y-values associated with a measured height (z-values).
Part of the list is plotted [below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etVw1.png). As you can see, there is a periodic arranged structure, namely a cross.
Now I would like to determine the distance (dx and dy) between neighboring characteristics of the crosses. Any hints how I could solve my problem?

To do so, first I was thinking to force Mma to search for a distinct characteristic within every cross (any outer corner, the center, whatever is usefull) But the dataset offers some roughness and I got stucked.

So determining the "mass center point" of each cross will be the best I guess. But again: any hints how to do that?

Thanks for any help!

[image]

**EDIT**

some example data are now provided, just download [here](https://upload.uni-jena.de/data/5717c0b1b79268.74729920/data.dat)

**EDIT2**

Thanks to **Sjoerd C. de Vries**, I made some more precise comments regarding the feature and the characteristic I'm looking for...

Comment: Difficult to say with no code and no data to play with...

Comment: true! data are now available...

Answer (score 6):

This can be done using image processing like I did [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3843/57).

Get the data:

```
data = Import["https://upload.uni-jena.de/data/5717c0b1b79268.74729920/data.dat"];
```

Convert to an image:

```
img = Image@ListDensityPlot[data, AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All, 
                                  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Frame -> False, 
                                  ImageSize -> 1200];
```

Interactively select the feature you're interested in:

```
pt = {ImageDimensions[img]/4, ImageDimensions[img]/2};
LocatorPane[
  Dynamic[pt], 
  Dynamic[
    Show[
      img, 
      Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[], Rectangle @@ pt}]
    ]
  ], 
 Appearance -> Graphics[{Red, AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[{0, 0}]}]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Find matching features:

```
res = ComponentMeasurements[
  MorphologicalComponents[
   ColorNegate[
    Binarize[
     ImageCorrelate[img, ImageTrim[img, pt], 
      NormalizedSquaredEuclideanDistance], 0.27]]], "Centroid"]
```

> {1 -> {666.747, 964.006}, 2 -> {415.396, 886.665},   3 -> {165.456,
>   807.965}, 4 -> {997.775, 788.42},   5 -> {745.466, 709.964}, 6 -> {494.535, 631.51},   7 -> {243.714, 554.783}, 8 -> {1075.23, 533.22}, 
>   9 -> {824.081, 457.244}, 10 -> {569.194, 376.724},   11 -> {901.547,
>   203.704}}

Show the results:

```
Show[img, 
 Graphics[{Green, FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Black], 
   Rectangle @@@ (TranslationTransform[# - Mean[pt]][pt] & /@ 
      res[[All, 2]])}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Find the distances between all the features that were found:

```
Outer[EuclideanDistance, res[[All, 2]], res[[All, 2]], 1]
(* {{0., 262.981, 525.015, 374.713, 265.958, 374.447, 588.575, 593.661, 530.623, 595.329, 795.732}, 
    {262.981, 0., 262.037, 590.608, 374.392, 267.146, 373.658, 748.533, 592.812, 532.629, 838.319}, 
    {525.015, 262.037, 0., 832.548, 588.231, 373.402, 265., 950.352, 746.185, 590.739, 952.344}, 
    {374.713, 590.608, 832.548, 0., 264.225, 527.135, 789.427, 266.695, 373.961, 594.285, 592.581}, 
    {265.958, 374.392, 588.231, 264.225, 0., 262.91, 525.201, 374.141, 264.665, 376.989, 529.774}, 
    {374.447, 267.146, 373.402, 527.135, 262.91, 0., 262.294, 588.952, 372.786, 265.499, 590.488}, 
    {588.575, 373.658, 265., 789.427, 525.201, 262.294, 0., 831.794, 588.507, 371.002, 745.654}, 
    {593.661, 748.533, 950.352, 266.695, 374.141, 588.952, 831.794, 0., 262.387, 529.68, 372.486}, 
    {530.623, 592.812, 746.185, 373.961, 264.665, 372.786, 588.507, 262.387, 0., 267.303, 265.11}, 
    {595.329, 532.629, 590.739, 594.285, 376.989, 265.499, 371.002, 529.68, 267.303, 0., 374.692}, 
    {795.732, 838.319, 952.344, 592.581, 529.774, 590.488, 745.654, 372.486, 265.11, 374.692, 0.}} *)
```

Now you only need to convert these distances in image coordinates in the original coordinates...

Comment: Looks nice, I will definitely have a look on this. However, here I just selected a tiny amount of data for a MWE. Finally, I do not want to go over the data manually, but I was hoping for some sort of automatic algorithm. Looks like it isn't that simple though.

Comment: @kay Well, at least you need to define what makes up a feature, otherwise this problem seems underdetermined.

Comment: As I wrote above, maybe: _[...] determining the "mass center point" of each cross [...]_ but, that is just an example. In principle it can be any feature linked to the cross (any outer corner, the center, whatever, ...). Finally I want to know, if there are some artificial modulations on that (feature-)distances. Hope that was somehow clearer...

Comment: In your question you seemed to suggest that the cross was just an example of something to look for: "there are some periodic features (in this case a cross)". That was what I was referring to when I wrote "defining the feature". I wasn't referring to a characteristic of this feature (such as center or bounding box).

Comment: Sorry for any missleading explanations from my side... I'm not a native speaker, as you might have guessed already.