# ImageTransformation and corresponding points

Tags: image-processing, coordinate-transformation

I have identified a list of corresponding points on two different images manually. I have found the geometrical transformation between such sets of points using `FindGeometricTransform` and I would now like to transform one of my images according to such transformation. When I do so, however, Mathematica gives me a completely black image and I don't understand how to get the first image transformed.

Here are the images:

[image: First image, i10]
[image: Second image, i15]

I import them with:

```
i10 = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdx00.jpg"];
i15 = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/XApmx.jpg"];
```

The lists of corresponding points are:

```
pts10 = {{1934.77615025538`, 
1576.1190734112033`}, {2058.4519305241565`, 
1405.2746195470152`}, {1594.8656770702503`, 
1522.0661370677385`}, {1717.5432392405596`, 
1641.0491448965918`}};

pts15 = {{1821.159315341623`, 
2432.200159743154`}, {1935.081765338483`, 
2254.0263438834454`}, {1476.992138438835`, 
2391.701747362471`}, {1604.3856168362227`, 2505.453543001129`}};
```

This command finds the transformation:

```
f = FindGeometricTransform[pts15, pts10, TransformationClass -> "Rigid"][[2]]
```

The following command, however, gives a black image:

```
ImageTransformation[i10, f]
```

Am I doing something wrong? Thanks

Comment: I think the major point can be found in the details section of `ImageTransformation`: "In 2D, the range of the coordinate system for the input image is assumed to be {{0,1},{0,a}}, where a is the aspect ratio. The bottom-left corner of the image corresponds to coordinates {0,0} by default." So while you found the transformation in pixel coordinates, `ImageTransformation` works as if a squared image (of any size) is in `[0,1]^2`.

Comment: That being said, you see a black image, because your transformation doesn't move the image a tiny bit like you assume. It moves the image way out of the region where you could see anything leaving only the black background that is filled in.

Comment: I suspect this question is a [duplicate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3843/7167).  In any case @sjoerd's solution is a great resource if you plan on performing this function regularly.

Answer (score 1):

I get different corresponding points when evaluating: `pts=ImageCorrespondingPoints[i10,i15]`? See: `MapThread[HighlightImage[#1, #2] &, {{i10, i15}, ImageCorrespondingPoints[i10, i15]}].`

You probably selected them manually? Since you are working with pixel positions I would propose that you display a plot of the coordinates, e.g. of `pts10`, `pts15` and transformed data of `pts10`.

```
pts10 = {{1934.77615025538`, 
1576.1190734112033`}, {2058.4519305241565`, 
1405.2746195470152`}, {1594.8656770702503`, 
1522.0661370677385`}, {1717.5432392405596`, 
1641.0491448965918`}};

pts15 = {{1821.159315341623`, 
2432.200159743154`}, {1935.081765338483`, 
2254.0263438834454`}, {1476.992138438835`, 
2391.701747362471`}, {1604.3856168362227`, 2505.453543001129`}};
```

I use here for demonstration `TransformationClass -> "Translation"`:

```
{e, t} = FindGeometricTransform[pts15, pts10, TransformationClass -> "Translation"];

transformedData = t[pts10]

(* {{1818.89,2430.52},{1934.78,2254.31},{1476.9,2391.75},{1604.78,2505.12}} *)

symbolPlus = Graphics[{Blue, Line[{{{-1, 0}, {1, 0}}, {{0, -1}, {0, 1}}}]}];
symbolCross = Graphics[{Line[{{{-1, -1}, {1, 1}}, {{-1, 1}, {1, -1}}}]}];

ListPlot[{pts10, transformedData, pts15}, 
 PlotMarkers -> {{symbolPlus, 0.04}, {symbolCross, 0.04}, {symbolCross, 0.04}}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Green}, FrameLabel -> {{"y (pixels)", ""}, {"x (pixels)", ""}}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 15, FontFamily -> "Calibri"}, ImageSize -> 600, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {{1400, 2100}, {1300, 2600}}]
```

[image]

When I use another `TransformationClass` then the transformed data of `pts10` (red) and the data `pts15` (green) fit nearly exactly on top of each other. The blue plus signs correspond to the orginal points `pts10`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that corresponding points are found correctly, you may still see black image because transformed image is out of frame of original image. To fix that, I suggest adding following options:

```
ImageTransformation[i10, f, DataRange -> Full, PlotRange -> All]
```

This should ensure that no data points are lost and field of view covers them all.