# How to digitize and edit a plot in Mathematica, which is produced by another software?

Tags: plotting, graphics, image-processing

For my thesis, I have produced all my plots with Mathematica. Now, I need to incorporate two plots, which are produced by another software and I don't have the source code anymore. Here is one of the plots:

[image]

Is there any way that I can import this image in Mathematica in order to change its fonts, colors, style, etc.?

One command which I found is:

```
ImageGraphics[img, Method -> "DualMarchingSquares"]
```

but this still does not allow me to modify the style of the plot.

Comment: See perhaps [How can I extract data points from a black and white image?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3831/27951) and [Recovering data points from an image](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1524/27951) for a starting point.

Comment: You could try to import the picture, extract the lines without the frame, create a new frame in the style you want  and then make an inset with the extracted picture into the new frame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to import the image. The coordinates of the image will depend on how you import it. Therefore, the actual values in the following will presumably be different in your case.

I use "DuckCapture" the import the picture without frame. This gives me

```
im
```

[image]

Next you create the frame as you want it. E.g.

```
Graphics[{}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameStyle -> {{{Red, Large}, Automatic}, {{Large, Green}, 
    Automatic}}, PlotRange -> {{2, 9}, {-5, 100}}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Now you need to place the scaled image inside the frame. This needs some fiddling and your numbers will be different (it needs some work):

```
gr = Graphics[{im}, AspectRatio -> 0.95, Frame -> False];
Graphics[{Point[{0, 0}], Inset[gr, {2, 0}, {0, 0}, 7.3]}, 
 Frame -> True, 
 FrameStyle -> {{{Red, Large}, Automatic}, {{Large, Green}, 
    Automatic}}, PlotRange -> {{2, 9}, {-5, 100}}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Addendum

To extract only part of a picture you can use e.g. "ImageTrim". E.g.:

```
im1
```

[image]

```
ImageTrim[im1, {{40, 40}, {310, 250}}]
```

[image]

Comment: No, the black frame inside is an artefact of DuckCapture

Comment: Have a look to what I added