# How to plot a curve with an experimental plot

Tags: plotting, fitting, interpolation

There is an experimental curve in this paper : https://arxiv.org/pdf/1211.2616.pdf

( Fig. 21. ) I want to make a new plot of the experimental curve with my theoretical model curve. How to do so by Mathematica ?

The graph I would like to plot is something like:

[image]

Comment: Please ask yourself: Did you give us enough to work on your problem? [We expect](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):
❌ A clear description of an on-topic problem or goal.
❌ A minimal working *Wolfram Language* code example, formatted, easy to *copy&paste*, in [Raw InputForm](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/RawInputForm.html). 
❌ An example of what you expect as output.
❌ Some proof of minimal *Mathematica* knowledge.
❌ Minimum due diligence: Share how you have searched the site and documentation, your attempts and reasons to believe an answer exists.

Comment: Try extracting the data from the plot (see. e.g. [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3831/how-can-i-extract-data-points-from-a-black-and-white-image?noredirect=1&lq=1) ) Then you can plot the data using `ListPlot` and overlay it with a standard Plot of your theoretical function.

Comment: I am voting to close as this seems to be a duplicate to previous questions on extracting data. The plotting itself can be found in the documentation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I extract data points from a black and white image?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3831/how-can-i-extract-data-points-from-a-black-and-white-image)

Comment: This may be a duplicate, it's hard to know given the very poor description of the problem. The OP should [edit] the question to avoid or revert closing. On it's current form this question is not suitable for the site. @Dr.Phy please improve your question.

Comment: I thought plus extracting, maybe there are other procedures like `Overlay`, but `Overlay` which I tried requires many align of the figure and the plot, like `AspectRatio` and so. Thanks anyways for all the replies

Comment: I'm not sure if it speaks good or bad about our community that @Dr.phy got away with positing a very bad question and still got a good answer.

Comment: @rhermans. The question was simple for me, so I wanted to earn some points. `:)`

Comment: @rhermans I don't think it says anything bad that a user decided to answer this question. That's quite good from my point of view. Particularly when taking into consideration the comment under the answer `I only took the data from Table 2 on page15 from paper`.  The two upvotes on this question, though, might say something negative about the site.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the author of the OP should have demonstrated some more effort, namely at least provide the data from the linked paper in a form easy to copy and paste.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```
H0 = 70;
\[CapitalOmega]\[CapitalLambda] = 0.73;
\[CapitalOmega]M = 0.27;
H[z_] := H0*(\[CapitalOmega]\[CapitalLambda] + \[CapitalOmega]M*(1 + 
     z)^3 + (1 - \[CapitalOmega]\[CapitalLambda] - 
 \[CapitalOmega]M)*(1 + z)^2)^(1/2)
 
data0 = {{2.3, Around[66.5, 7.4]}, {2.3, Around[67.8, 2.4]}, {0.35, 
Around[60.8, 3.6]}, {0.35, Around[62.5, 5.2]}, {0.57, 
Around[58.8, 2.9]}, {0.44, Around[57.4, 5.4]}, {0.60, 
Around[54.9, 3.8]}, {0.73, Around[56.2, 4.0]}};
data1 = {{0.2, Around[1.11, 0.17]*H0}, {0.4, 
Around[0.83, 0.13]*H0}, {0.6, Around[0.81, 0.08]*H0}, {0.8, 
Around[0.83, 0.1]*H0}};
data2 = {{0, Around[73.8, 2.5]}};

Show[{Plot[H[z]/(1 + z), {z, -0.4, 2.4}, AxesOrigin -> {-1/2, 50}, 
AxesLabel -> {z, "H[z]/(1+z) (km/sec/Mpc)"}, PlotRange -> All], 
ListPlot[{data0, data1, data2}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Black, Green}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: @Dr. phy    Of course, you can tweak and improve my code to your liking.

Comment: Yeah, that's very much helpful. I meant there are of course other ways to go around extract.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk how did you extract the data?

Comment: @rhermans .I only took the data from `Table 2` on page`15` from paper .