# Computing the distance between two curves obtained from image data?

Tags: list-manipulation, image-processing

I've got some image data that I've binarized.  The image contains two curves, from which I'd like to compute the distance between (eventually computing an average radius for each point in the picture).  I've done the computation, but it's done in C programmer style, and fairly ugly

```
data = ImageData[ b ] ;
{h, w} = Dimensions[data] ;

min = Table[0, {w}] ;
max = Table[0, {w}] ;
averageRadiusList = {} ;
scale = 0.1 / w  ;

For [ column = 1, column < w + 1, column++,
 For [ row = 1, row < h/2, row++,
   If [
    data[[row, column]] != 1,
       min[[column]] =  row ; Break
    ]
   ]
  For [ row = h, row > h/2, row--,
   If [
    data[[row, column]] != 1,
      max[[column]] =  row ; Break
    ]
   ]
  If [ min[[column]] !=  0  && max[[column]] != 0,

   AppendTo[
    averageRadiusList, {column * scale,
     scale * (max[[column]] - min[[column]])/2} ]
   ]
 ]
```

I was wondering if there's a more natural "Mathematica way" of doing things ... something that is presumably more elegant, efficient, compact, and more general?

Comment: Did you check the [question]: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1524 which explains some data obtained from a picture with nice mathematica functions.

Comment: Can use "fast marching" to move from one curve equidistantly outward, stopping when you hit the other. Code for this sort of thing can be found at

http://blog.wolfram.com/data/uploads/2010/12/NavigatingtheBlenheimMaze.nb

That notebook is explained, to an extent, in the corresponding company blog from a while back.

http://blog.wolfram.com/2010/12/07/navigating-the-blenheim-maze/

Comment: Or can use Nearest on the first set of pixels to create a NearestFunction object. Then iterate over the second set using that NearestFunction, taking the closest in set 1 to each pixel in set 2. Finally take the pair that gives the min distance.

Comment: I was able to follow and replicate the steps up to producing the table of colour disks, but couldn't get the Image@Replace step to work for me.  In that step there's more fancy syntax that I don't understand than I do.  I guess what I'm really looking for is a way to extract just the locations of the 0 pixels without using a set of nested For[] loops.

Comment: Here is what that syntax means. {col[[3]] -> 1, _ :> 0} suggests we take the color value stored in part 3 of `col` and replace any instance of that with the number 1.  Anything else gets replaced with zero. The rule delayed :> is used because we don't know ahead of time what other things might need replaced. We've manually binarized the image. `Replace` is done at level 2 only, hence the `{2}`. This means we will replace the elements in the image data matrix.  If I had used {1} it would have operated on the rows and replaced them with 0 since none of the rows match `col[[3]]`.

Comment: For speed, it looks like this code would benefit from compiling. Instead of `AppendTo` you could use a Bag.

Comment: I think I was also confused about the Image@ part.  Looking at @ in the help it appears you are using two different forms of function call syntax in this statement, one function passing params with [] and the other passing with @?  Is there a reason for mixing syntax here?

Comment: I don't find Bag in the help?

Comment: Since you have enough rep to comment, you should make such remarks as comments :)

Comment: @PeeterJoot ``Internal`Bag`` is an undocumented function. You can find some information plus links to other sources [in this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/845/46)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lets start with an example image

```
img = Binarize@
  Image[Plot[{Sin[2 x], 2 + Cos[3 x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Axes -> False, 
    PlotStyle -> Black, Background -> White, ImagePadding -> None, 
    PlotRangePadding -> {None, .1}]]
```

[image: example image]

To find the distance between the two curves you could do something like

```
data = ImageData[img];
w = Dimensions[data][[2]];
scale = .1/w;

averageRadiusList = Reap[Sow @@@ Position[data, 0], Range[w],
    {scale #1, scale (Max[#2] - Min[#2])/2} &][[2, All, 1]];

ListPlot[averageRadiusList]
```

[image: radius]

What this code does is to find the indices of all black points in `img`. The combination of `Sow` and `Reap` will effectively group these coordinates by their column index and for each group return `{scale c, scale (Max[rows]-Min[rows])/2}` where `c` is the column index, and `rows` is a list of row indices of all black points in the plot that have column index `c`.