# Findfit does not find the best fit

Tags: fitting

I am working on a project that needs curve fitting. The experimental data should be fitted with a model that calculated with an integration equation.
At first, I enter my experimental data

```
    ClearAll[data, L, P, z0, alpha0, Leff, landa, w0, w, I0, II, q, Q, T, t, z, beta, Is];
data = {{-11.`, 0.989518737`}, {-10.8`, 0.986423266`}, {-10.6`, 
0.988486913`}, {-10.4`, 0.988486913`}, {-10.2`, 
0.98745509`}, {-10.`, 0.988486913`}, {-9.8`, 
0.988486913`}, {-9.6`, 0.99055056`}, {-9.4`, 0.98745509`}, {-9.2`,
 0.984359619`}, {-9.`, 0.989518737`}, {-8.8`, 
0.983327796`}, {-8.6`, 0.98745509`}, {-8.4`, 
0.984359619`}, {-8.2`, 0.992614207`}, {-8.`, 
0.996741501`}, {-7.8`, 0.996741501`}, {-7.6`, 
0.989518737`}, {-7.4`, 0.991582384`}, {-7.2`, 
0.998805148`}, {-7.`, 0.996741501`}, {-6.8`, 
0.995709678`}, {-6.6`, 0.995709678`}, {-6.4`, 
0.994677854`}, {-6.2`, 1.001900619`}, {-6.`, 1.00809156`}, {-5.8`,
 1.006027913`}, {-5.6`, 1.009123383`}, {-5.4`, 
0.996741501`}, {-5.2`, 0.994677854`}, {-5.`, 
1.018409795`}, {-4.8`, 1.020473442`}, {-4.6`, 
1.023568912`}, {-4.4`, 1.024600736`}, {-4.2`, 
1.027696206`}, {-4.`, 1.030791677`}, {-3.8`, 
1.033887147`}, {-3.6`, 1.030791677`}, {-3.4`, 
1.02872803`}, {-3.2`, 1.0318235`}, {-3.`, 1.036982618`}, {-2.8`, 
1.041109912`}, {-2.6`, 1.042141735`}, {-2.4`, 
1.038014441`}, {-2.2`, 1.034918971`}, {-2.`, 1.0318235`}, {-1.8`, 
1.024600736`}, {-1.6`, 1.014282501`}, {-1.4`, 
1.004996089`}, {-1.2`, 0.994677854`}, {-1.`, 
0.980232325`}, {-0.8`, 0.960627679`}, {-0.6`, 
0.936895738`}, {-0.4`, 0.909036504`}, {-0.2`, 0.886336387`}, {0.`,
 0.865699917`}, {0.2`, 0.860540799`}, {0.4`, 0.883240916`}, {0.6`,
 0.936895738`}, {0.8`, 0.981264149`}, {1.`, 0.991582384`}, {1.2`, 
1.026664383`}, {1.4`, 1.033887147`}, {1.6`, 1.046269029`}, {1.8`, 
1.036982618`}, {2.`, 1.044205382`}, {2.2`, 1.041109912`}, {2.4`, 
1.0318235`}, {2.6`, 1.030791677`}, {2.8`, 1.026664383`}, {3.`, 
1.030791677`}, {3.2`, 1.032855324`}, {3.4`, 1.0318235`}, {3.6`, 
1.027696206`}, {3.8`, 1.02872803`}, {4.`, 1.023568912`}, {4.2`, 
1.020473442`}, {4.4`, 1.015314324`}, {4.6`, 1.013250677`}, {4.8`, 
1.013250677`}, {5.`, 1.009123383`}, {5.2`, 1.007059736`}, {5.4`, 
1.006027913`}, {5.6`, 1.004996089`}, {5.8`, 1.006027913`}, {6.`, 
1.003964266`}, {6.2`, 1.002932442`}, {6.4`, 1.000868795`}, {6.6`, 
0.998805148`}, {6.8`, 0.999836972`}, {7.`, 0.996741501`}, {7.2`, 
0.993646031`}, {7.4`, 0.992614207`}, {7.6`, 0.99055056`}, {7.8`, 
0.991582384`}, {8.`, 0.989518737`}, {8.2`, 0.988486913`}, {8.4`, 
0.98745509`}, {8.6`, 0.985391443`}, {8.8`, 0.986423266`}, {9.`, 
0.985391443`}};
```

The initial value of some variables are:

```
L = 0.12;
P = 0.035;
z0 = 0.8;
alpha0 = 3.4302;
```

And some other functions and variables are built as:

```
Leff = (1 - E^(-alpha0*L))/alpha0;
landa = 532*10^-7;
w0 = Sqrt[(landa*z0)/Pi];
w[z_] = w0*Sqrt[1 + (z/z0)^2];
I0 = (2*P)/(Pi*w0^2);
II[z_] = (2*P)/(Pi*(w[z])^2);
q[z_, beta_] = (beta*I0*Leff)/(1 + (z/z0)^2);
Q[z_, Is_] = Exp[(alpha0*L*II[z])/(II[z] + Is)];
```

And at last the model equation is built as:

```
T[(beta_)?NumericQ, (Is_)?NumericQ, (z_)?NumericQ] = Q[z, Is]/(Sqrt[Pi]*q[z, beta])*NIntegrate[Log[1 + q[z, beta]*Exp[-t^2]], {t, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}];
```

Now we have `FindFit` to find `beta` and `Is`: (the range of `beta` and `Is` are obtained by repeat the code to find a curve fitting near the experimental data, and if any other range results better fitting so that will be accepted.)

```
fit = FindFit[data, {T[beta, Is, z], 1.2*10^-2 < beta < 1.4*10^-2,500 < Is <550}, {beta, Is}, z]
Show[Plot[T[beta, Is, z] /. fit, {z, -11, 9}, PlotRange -> All],ListPlot[data]]
```

And the result is:

[image]

I expect that the regions shown below, should have the better agreement:

[image]

I really thank you if you could help or guide me to have a better result.

Comment: Can you show that for your given function the fit is incorrect? It is really difficult to tell as you prescribe a fairly complex fitting function.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Real data doesn't always match a desired theoretical curve.  Your theoretical curve has only two parameters with one essentially being used up to center the fit and just a single parameter to fit the shape.  You might want to use `Manipulate` to modify the shape parameter to see if the theoretical curve is flexible enough to match the data.

Comment: I came up with my answer using reasoning similar to that in @JimBaldwin 's comment. We can say that the family of functions that would be shown with `Manipulate` are used as a (non-orthogonal) basis to describe the data.

Answer (score 15):

It seems it is better to use a family of functions instead of just one. The code below uses `NonLinearFit` instead of `FindFit`, since I do not think using `FindFit` is a hard requirement in the question.

Also, below I assume that the definitions in the question are evaluated.

First, let us speed-up the use of `NIntegrate`:

```
T[(beta_)?NumericQ, (Is_)?NumericQ, (z_)?NumericQ] := 
  Q[z, Is]/(Sqrt[Pi]*q[z, beta])*
   NIntegrate[
    Log[1 + q[z, beta]*Exp[-t^2]], {t, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, 
    PrecisionGoal -> 3, 
    Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}];
```

Second, let us select and plot a family of functions:

```
funcs = Flatten@
   Table[T[beta, Is, z], {beta, 1.2*10^-2, 1.4*10^-2, 0.1*10^-2}, {Is, 500, 550, 5}];

Plot[funcs, {z, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]
```

[image]

(I selected the functions using the ranges of the parameters given to FindFit in the question.)

Next we create linear combinations variables:

```
vars = Array[a, Length[funcs]];
```

...and do a model fit:

```
fm = NonlinearModelFit[data, vars.funcs, vars, z, 
  Method -> "NMinimize"]
```

Notice the choice of the method. With the default method I was getting singular curves (which were still providing a good fit).

Finally, we plot the data and the model function:

```
Show[ListPlot[data], 
 Plot[fm[x], {x, -10, 10}, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]]
```

[image]

This question and my response are very similar to [Non-linear curve fit problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95688/non-linear-curve-fit-problem/).

Comment: The command: fm = NonlinearModelFit[data, vars.funcs, vars, z, 
  Method -> "Minimize"] has something wrong, when I run it, this error happens: NonlinearModelFit::bdmtd: Value of option Method -> Minimize is not Automatic, "Gradient", "ConjugateGradient", "InteriorPoint", "QuasiNewton", "Newton", "NMinimize", or "LevenbergMarquardt". >>

Comment: @Mirzaie.rz Sorry, it seems it was auto-corrected when I pasted the command. It should be "NMinimize".

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, the final fitting in your code is very ideal, but as I know this fitting is a combination of 'T[beta,Is,z]', however I need a single value for 'beta' and 'Is'. Is there any way to fit these data  with a single 'T'?

Comment: @Mirzaie.rz What do you mean: (1) a single function with only two parameters, beta and Is, or (2) a function that has the form of `T`?

Comment: (1) a single function with only two parameters, beta and Is (Like my first code that i used Findfit)

Comment: @Mirzaie.rz Look at `Normal[fm]`. You should be able to represent it as `T1[b0_, s0_, z_] :=  Sum[a[i,j]*T[b0 + i*bh, s0 + j*sh, z], {i, 1, 20}, {j, 1, 10}]`.

Comment: You could speed up the `NIntegrate` even more by replacing it with `(-Sqrt[\[Pi]] PolyLog[3/2, -q[z, beta]])`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Nice observation!