# Fitting Coxian distribution to some data

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting, distributions

I'm trying to fit a transformed (actually shifted to the right) Coxian distribution to some data ( if needed an example set is here [Sim data](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/315629/StackExchange/fitData.txt) ).
I've tried a number of ways for this:

1. `FindDistributionParameters` in my case yields the worst results.
2. `FindFit` to fit the PDF of the distribution to a `HistogramList` works the best atm
3. `NMinimize` the distance between the distribution moments to data moments

I as well tried to combine those methods by providing the starting values (and here random starting values work a little bit better than some meaningfull values obtained via `FindInstance`).

My question is how to enchance my solutions and why some of them do not work like others?

Here's something I tried:
(Off-topic question - how can I hide some part of the post for it not to be long?)

---

The first approach is with direct `FindDistributionParameters`

```
simData = 
  Import["fitData.txt", "Table"];

phasesToUse = 3;
distrShift = 10;
distrStart = 0;

Clear[coxModel];
coxModel[p_] := coxModel[p] = TransformedDistribution[
    x + distrShift,
    x \[Distributed] CoxianDistribution[
      Table[\[Alpha][j], {j, 1, p - 1}],
      Table[\[Lambda][j], {j, 1, p}]
      ]
    ];
Clear[coxModelPDF];
coxModelPDF[p_] := coxModelPDF[p] = PDF[
    coxModel[p],
    x
    ];

resFindParam = FindDistributionParameters[
   simData,
   coxModel[phasesToUse]
   ];

resFindParam
Show[{
  Histogram[simData, {0.5}, "PDF"],
  Plot[
   (*Evaluate[*)coxModelPDF[x](*]*),
   {x, distrShift, 30}
   ]
  }]
```

[image]

As you can see, `FindDistributionParameters` failed horribly here. Think it found some local minimum and failed to find anything better.

---

Next I tried to supply an initial guess by finding a point that fits the first moment of data:

```
initVals = FindInstance[
     Evaluate[And @@ Join[
        {0.9 <= Moment[coxModel[phasesToUse], 1]/
          Moment[simData[[All, pointToApprox]], 1] <= 1.1},
        {coxModelPDF[phasesToUse, distrShift] == distrStart},
        Table[0 <= \[Alpha][i] <= 1, {i, 1, phasesToUse - 1}],
        Table[\[Lambda][i] >= 0, {i, 1, phasesToUse}]
        ]],
     Join[
      Table[\[Alpha][i], {i, 1, phasesToUse - 1}],
      Table[\[Lambda][i], {i, 1, phasesToUse}]
      ]
     ][[1]] /. {\[Alpha] -> \[Alpha]I, \[Lambda] -> \[Lambda]I};
resFindParam = FindDistributionParameters[
   simData[[All, pointToApprox]],
   coxModel[phasesToUse],
   Join[
     Table[{\[Alpha][i], \[Alpha]I[i]}, {i, 1, phasesToUse - 1}],
     Table[{\[Lambda][i], \[Lambda]I[i]}, {i, 1, phasesToUse}]
     ] /. initVals
   ];
```

Unfo, in this case it repeats the previous case or just almost infinitely tries to find parameters.

---

Then I tried to `NMinimize` the distance between at least the first two moments and then to feed it to `FindDistributionParameters`:

```
simData = 
  Import["fitData.txt", "Table"];

momentsToMin = 2;
phasesToUse = 3;
distrShift = 10;

Clear[simMoment];
simMoment[n_, i_] := simMoment[n, i] = Moment[
    simData,
    i
    ];

Clear[coxMoment];
coxMoment[p_, i_] := coxMoment[p, i] = Moment[
    TransformedDistribution[
     x + distrShift,
     x \[Distributed] CoxianDistribution[
       Table[\[Alpha]T[i, j], {j, 1, p - 1}],
       Table[\[Lambda]T[i, j], {j, 1, p}]
       ]
     ],
    i
    ];

tmpEnum = 0;
minRes = NMinimize[
   {
    Evaluate[Plus @@ Table[
       SquaredEuclideanDistance[
        Join[Table[\[Alpha][i], {i, 1, phasesToUse - 1}], 
         Table[\[Lambda][i], {i, 1, phasesToUse}]],
        Join[Table[\[Alpha]T[k, j], {j, 1, phasesToUse - 1}], 
         Table[\[Lambda]T[k, j], {j, 1, phasesToUse}]]
        ],
       {k, 1, momentsToMin}
       ]],
    Evaluate[And @@ Join[
       {PDF[
          TransformedDistribution[
           x + distrShift,
           x \[Distributed] CoxianDistribution[
             Table[\[Alpha][i], {i, 1, phasesToUse - 1}],
             Table[\[Lambda][i], {i, 1, phasesToUse}]
             ]
           ],
          distrShift
          ] == 0},
       Table[
        coxMoment[phasesToUse, k] == simMoment[pointToApprox, k],
        {k, 1, momentsToMin}
        ],
       Table[0 < \[Alpha][i] < 1, {i, 1, phasesToUse - 1}],
       Table[\[Lambda][i] > 0.01, {i, 1, phasesToUse}],
       Flatten[
        Table[0 < \[Alpha]T[k, j] < 1, {j, 1, phasesToUse - 1}, {k, 1,
           momentsToMin}]],
       Flatten[
        Table[\[Lambda]T[k, j] > 0.01, {j, 1, phasesToUse}, {k, 1, 
          momentsToMin}]]
       ]]
    },
   Join[
    Table[\[Alpha][i], {i, 1, phasesToUse - 1}],
    Table[\[Lambda][i], {i, 1, phasesToUse}],
    Flatten[
     Table[\[Alpha]T[k, j], {j, 1, phasesToUse - 1}, {k, 1, 
       momentsToMin}]],
    Flatten[
     Table[\[Lambda]T[k, j], {j, 1, phasesToUse}, {k, 1, 
       momentsToMin}]]
    ],
   EvaluationMonitor :> (tmpEnum++; 
     If[Mod[tmpEnum, 200] == 0, Print[tmpEnum];];)
   ];

distrRes = FindDistributionParameters[
   simData,
   TransformedDistribution[
    x + distrShift,
    x \[Distributed] CoxianDistribution[
      Table[\[Alpha]F[i], {i, 1, phasesToUse - 1}],
      Table[\[Lambda]F[i], {i, 1, phasesToUse}]
      ]
    ],
   Join[Table[{\[Alpha]F[i], \[Alpha][i]}, {i, 1, phasesToUse - 1}], 
     Table[{\[Lambda]F[i], \[Lambda][i]}, {i, 1, phasesToUse}]] /. 
    minRes[[2]]
   ];

minRes
distrRes
Show[{
  Histogram[simData, {0.5}, "PDF"],
  Plot[
   Evaluate[PDF[
     TransformedDistribution[
       x + distrShift,
       x \[Distributed] CoxianDistribution[
         Table[\[Alpha][i], {i, 1, phasesToUse - 1}],
         Table[\[Lambda][i], {i, 1, phasesToUse}]
         ]
       ] /. minRes[[2]],
     x
     ]],
   {x, distrShift, 30}
   ],
  Plot[
   Evaluate[PDF[
     TransformedDistribution[
       x + distrShift,
       x \[Distributed] CoxianDistribution[
         Table[\[Alpha]F[i], {i, 1, phasesToUse - 1}],
         Table[\[Lambda]F[i], {i, 1, phasesToUse}]
         ]
       ] /. distrRes,
     x
     ]],
   {x, distrShift, 30},
   PlotStyle -> Red
   ]
  }]
```

The result is:

[image]

Where the blue line is for the parameters after `NMinimize` and the red is for `FindDistributionParameters` after that.
This is better now, but still not the best thing. Yet it is possible to obtain better results.

---

The last thing I tried is to directly fit the PDF to the HistogramList

```
simData = 
  Import["fitData.txt", "Table"];

phasesToUse = 3;
distrShift = 10;
distrStart = 0;

histStep = 0.5;

tmpFitData = 
  HistogramList[simData, {histStep}, "PDF"];
fitData = 
  Join[{{tmpFitData[[1, 1]], 0}}, 
   Table[{(tmpFitData[[1, i + 1]] + tmpFitData[[1, i]])/2, 
     tmpFitData[[2, i]]}, {i, 1, Length[tmpFitData[[2]]]}]];

Clear[coxModel];
coxModel[p_] := coxModel[p] = TransformedDistribution[
    x + distrShift,
    x \[Distributed] CoxianDistribution[
      Table[\[Alpha][j], {j, 1, p - 1}],
      Table[\[Lambda][j], {j, 1, p}]
      ]
    ];
Clear[coxModelPDF];
coxModelPDF[p_, x_] := coxModelPDF[p, x] = PDF[
    coxModel[p],
    x
    ];

fitPars = FindFit[
   fitData,
   {
    coxModelPDF[phasesToUse, x],
    Evaluate[And @@ Join[
       {coxModelPDF[phasesToUse, distrShift] == distrStart},
       Table[0 < \[Alpha][i] < 1, {i, 1, phasesToUse - 1}],
       Table[\[Lambda][i] > 0.01, {i, 1, phasesToUse}](*,
       Flatten[Table[(\[Lambda][i]/\[Lambda][
       j]\[LessEqual]0.95||\[Lambda][i]/\[Lambda][
       j]\[GreaterEqual]1.05),{i,1,phasesToUse},{j,i+1,
       phasesToUse}]]*)
       ]]
    },
   Join[
    Table[\[Alpha][i], {i, 1, phasesToUse - 1}],
    Table[\[Lambda][i], {i, 1, phasesToUse}]
    ],
   x(*,
   MaxIterations\[Rule]1000*),
   Method -> NMinimize(*,
   NormFunction\[Rule](Norm[#, 2] & )*)
   ];

fitPars
Show[{
  Histogram[simData, {0.5}, "PDF"],
  Plot[
   Evaluate[coxModelPDF[phasesToUse, x] /. fitPars],
   {x, distrShift, 30}
   ]
  }]
```

Result:
[image]

This is the best I could obtain till now. But I'm sure that there is a way to find a better fit and/or improve my codes.

Any feedback is welcome and sorry for the long post.

Comment: Have you tried tweaking the `ParameterEstimator` setting?

Comment: Yes, I tried to try some different `ParameterEstimator` for `FindDistributionParameters`.
For example `ParameterEstimator -> {"MethodOfMoments", MaxIterations -> 500,   AccuracyGoal -> 8}` ignores the distribution assumptions.
And other come to the same result - flat line or ignore assumptions as well.

Comment: My suggestion is to subtract the minimum data value from all data points and then add 0.0001 (as the maximum likelihood estimate of the shift parameter is likely the minimum value or very close to that), write the code for `p=2`, use only 100 sample points (rather than 20,000) to get things working, use `FindDistributionParameters` without the shift parameter to get starting values, and finally use  `FindDistributionParameters` with all parameters (including the shift).  Then when that's working write the code for the general case.

Comment: And I would avoid any least-squares estimation for a density function (i.e., `FindFit`) like the plague.  (FindFit for least-squares estimation is fine.  Just not when you're estimating a density function from a random sample.)

Comment: `ParameterEstimator -> {"MaximumLikelihood", Method -> "NMaximize"}` does a semi-decent job here. The default estimator is failing quite badly, however.

Comment: @AndrewS. Is the question specifically about fitting Coxian distribution? If yes, I think the title should reflect that.

Comment: @JimBaldwin I tried playing with `FindDistributionParameters`, but I can't get it working well. THe worst thing I noticed is that you can't (or can you?) specify any constranits, for example assume that the resulting PDF must be 0 when x=0.
Even though `FindFit` is not recommended, it yields the best results atm.

@StefanR Somehow it likes to ignore distribution assumtions as well...

@AntonAntonov Yeah, changed it, as I really am interested in just CoxianDistribution.

Comment: Why does `FindDistributionParameters` in some cases ignore assumptions?
I as well noticed that when different lambdas are almost equal, fitting functions fail to go any further (finding some local extremum there?). What can I do in this case? Like explicitly specify in constraints (when aplicable) that their ratio should differ for at least 5%?

Answer (score 4):

Not an answer ... more a comment that is too long for the comment box. I found your question difficult to follow, mainly because it sets up lots of functions and models and this and that ... and all we really need to know -- which is not shown -- is what is the functional form of the pdf that you are actually using. And that appears to be:

```
p = 3;
PDF[TransformedDistribution[x + 10, x \[Distributed] 
CoxianDistribution[Table[\[Alpha][j], {j, 1, p - 1}], 
 Table[\[Lambda][j], {j, 1, p}]]], x] // Simplify
```

... which produces this output for the pdf:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/CoxiandDist.png))</sub>

... which is a model requiring that you estimate 5 separate parameters.

In summary:

- you have a fairly simple, almost elementary shaped empirical pdf (your histogram) ... which one should be able to easily capture beautifully with a 1 or 2 parameter distribution  ... and
- instead, you are trying to model it with a distribution that requires 5 parameters. Presumably you have some good solid foundation for using the Coxian model (????), but when it comes to estimation: *less is more*.

To illustrate the point neatly, here is a single parameter fit to your data using a Rayleigh distribution with pdf:

$$f(x) = \frac{x}{s^2} \exp \left(-\frac{x^2}{2 s^2}\right) \quad \text{ for } x > 0 $$

```
 sol = FindDistributionParameters[simData-10, RayleighDistribution[s]]
```

> {s -> 2.84301}

And here is the fit ... which is far better, with just a 1 parameter model than the 5 parameter Coxian:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/fittedRayleighmodel.png))</sub>

Comment: Thanks for this comment. I know that this smaple can be approximated using, for example, Rayleigh distribution really well. I deliberately chose Coxian distribution, as the next data (not included in the sample I provided) won't go well with Rayleight, but can be approximated with some phase type like Coxian and that's why I'm trying it on the first sample. +

Answer (score 4):

This answer uses multiple Coxian distributions to approximate the PDF for the data given in the question, [SimData](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/315629/StackExchange/fitData.txt). It is in the same spirit as of my answers to ["Findfit does not find the best fit"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/104759/findfit-does-not-find-the-best-fit/104761#104761) and ["Non-linear curve fit problem"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95688/non-linear-curve-fit-problem/95719#95719).

I think the answer fits the question request for

> "[...] how to enchance my solutions and why some of them do not work like
>   others?"

Using multiple Coxian PDF's is an enhancement, and the resutls probably explain why it is not easy to find good approximations using fittings of one Coxian PDF.

Also, examining a fitted sum of Coxian PDF's that gives a good approximation can help selecting the parameters for a single Coxian PDF if that is desired.

**Procedure outline**

1. Generate a basis of many (e.g. 20,000 or 100,000) Coxian PDF functions over a Cartesian product of parameter ranges. The parameter ranges are selected to be close to the observed distribution.
2. From the data make a set of PDF approximate estimates using large enough samples. (E.g. 10 or 30 sets of based on 2000 points each.) This is to help the next step.
3. Find a linear fit of the Coaxian PDF functions from step 1 to the points from step 2.
4. Verify the obtained result.

I did the fit using my [QuantileRegression package](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/blob/master/QuantileRegression.m) because using `LinearModelFit` was too slow and I was getting over-fitted results.

**Code**

**0**. Load the data

```
simData = Flatten@ Import["https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/315629/StackExchange/fitData.txt", "Table"];
simData = Transpose[{Range[Length[simData]], Flatten@simData}];
```

**1**. Generating a basis of many Coxian PDF functions (20,000 to 100,000):

```
pfuncs = Table[
   Piecewise[{{(\[Alpha]*\[Lambda]1*\[Lambda]2)/(E^(\[Lambda]2*(x - \
\[Mu]))*(\[Lambda]1 - \[Lambda]2)) + (\[Lambda]1*(1 - \[Alpha] + (\
\[Alpha]*\[Lambda]2)/(-\[Lambda]1 + \[Lambda]2)))/
              E^(\[Lambda]1*(x - \[Mu])), x - \[Mu] >= 0}}, 
    0], {\[Mu], 10.2, 12, 0.2}, {\[Alpha], 0, 1, 0.1}, {\[Lambda]1, 
    0.01, 3.5, 0.25}, {\[Lambda]2, 0.02, 13, 0.2}];
pfuncs = Union[Flatten[pfuncs]];
Length[pfuncs]

(* 91140 *)
```

Here is a sample of these basis functions:

[image]

**2**. Make "a dozen" (from 10 to 100) PDF approximations:

```
xMultPDFPairs = Table[(
    hl = HistogramList[RandomSample[simData[[All, 2]], 4000], 30, "PDF"]; 
    N@Transpose[{Mean /@ Partition[hl[[1]], 2, 1], hl[[2]]}]), {10}];
```

**3**. Fit the Coaxian PDF's to the PDF approximations:

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/master/QuantileRegression.m"]

AbsoluteTiming[
 qXPDFInt = 
  QuantileRegressionFit[Join @@ xMultPDFPairs, pfuncs, x, {0.5}, 
    Method -> {LinearProgramming, Method -> "CLP"}][[1]]
 ]
```

[image]

```
qXPDFInt = Simplify[qXPDFInt];
qXPDFInt = Function[Evaluate[qXPDFInt /. {x -> #}]]
```

[image]

**3.1**. This plots the PDF approximations points and the fitted Coxian linear model:

```
xps = Join @@ xMultPDFPairs;
Show[{ListLinePlot[{#, qXPDFInt[#]} & /@ Union[Sort[xps[[All, 1]]]], 
   PlotStyle -> Pink, PlotRange -> All], ListPlot[xps]}]
```

[image]

**4**. Verification with plots:

```
Show[{
  Histogram[simData[[All, 2]], 40, "PDF"],
  ListLinePlot[{#, qXPDFInt[#]} & /@ Union[Sort[xps[[All, 1]]]], 
   PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> All]}]
```

[image]

**Using B-splines over CDF's**

Before coming up with the answer above I used B-splines fitted over CDF approximate estimates. The resulting PDF was derived by differentiating the obtained B-spline CDF. Here is an example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for a comment. Yes, this way will yield a good approximation, but I'm looking exactly for a single Coxian distribution with some parameters (preferably the least possible amount of phases) which I'll compare later. Still thanks for sharing, I'll spend a bit more time a bit later. +

Comment: @AndrewS. Right, I thought you are looking for one fitted Coxian distribution. As I indicated in my answer, examining the fitted sum of several (seven) Coxian PDF's that gives a good approximation, might help selecting the parameters for the searched single Coxian PDF.

Comment: this might work, but first I'll try it head-on.

Comment: Pretty pic (the top one! - the RandomSample of basis funcs)

Comment: @wolfies Thanks, I thought that too!

Answer (score 4):

When one has a large sample from a continuous probability distribution as you do, one does not always need to be restricted to methods of fitting a specific distribution with a parsimonious number of parameters.

Yes, when you know the form of the distribution and just have to estimate a few parameters, that's great.  But if you don't have to compare specified parameters among data sets and just need to estimate the probability density function (and any summaries based on the probability density function), using nonparametric density estimation can be just what you need.

For example, if you're a Bayesian and don't (or can't) know the form of the posterior distribution, what's the next best thing? A very large sample from that posterior distribution.

*Mathematica* has the function `SmoothKernelDistribution` from which you can obtain estimates of the mean, variance, percentiles, probability density function (at any point), cumulative distribution function, etc.  Such summary statistics might be better things to compare among different data sets than parameters from a specific form of probability density function.  And you have the luxury of a large sample size (12,000 for your posted example).

Here are the commands that could be used:

```
kde = SmoothKernelDistribution[simData];
Show[Histogram[simData, "Knuth", "PDF", PlotRange -> {{9, 22}, Automatic}, Frame -> True], 
 Plot[PDF[kde, t], {t, 0, 1.1 Max[simData]}]]
```

[image: Nonparametric kernel density estimate]

Comment: Really nice. I like the concise fitting! I wanted to give a response in the same spirit (that is why I used B-splines initially), but then decided to go for the fitting with a large basis with Coxian PDF's.

Answer (score 2):

As @wolfies states you should likely consider simpler models to describe (as opposed to "explain") your data.  However, if you do need to use the Coxian distribution, then you might consider calculating AIC values for small values of `p` to help determine which value of `p` works best (with respect to AIC).

The maximum likelihood estimate of the shift parameter can probably be shown to be the minimum value observed in the data.  As such something like the following can be used to obtain the maximum likelihood estimates:

```
p = 3;
a = Table[α[j], {j, 1, p - 1}];
b = Table[λ[j], {j, 1, p}];

(* Estimate of shift parameter *)
shift = Min[simData] - 0.001

(* Estimate remaining parameters *)
sol = NMaximize[{LogLikelihood[CoxianDistribution[a, b], simData - shift],
  0 <= a <= 1 && b >= 0}, Flatten[{a, b}], MaxIterations -> 1000]
(* {-2020.24, {α[1] -> 0.962951, α[2] -> 0.999625, λ[1] -> 0.843055, 
   λ[2] -> 0.843053, λ[3] -> 0.843294}} *)

(* Calculate AIC to allow for comparisons among different values of p *)
aic = -2 sol[[1]] + 4 p
```

(I subtracted 0.001 from the minimum of the data so that `LogLikelihood` function wouldn't complain about a zero.)  I took just the first 1,000 of your 12,000 data values and it took about 1 minute to find the estimates.  Doing all 12,000 is likely to take a lot more than 12 times that amount of time.  (Do you really need 12,000 observations?)

Comment: Took me some time to test a few things. Thanks for this suggestion. However, the bad thing here is that this method with an additional condition uses a lot of RAM on my PC (goes up to 16 GB, when I forcefully terminate it). I need the PDF of the final distribution to be equall to 0 when x=0 (or for whatever starting point is). Still thanks for showing this method, I'll play a bit with it. ++