# How to find analytical expresion for data from image

Tags: image-processing, fitting

I need to find an analytical expression for the data collected from an image.

I found a relevant topic on how to extract the data in [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1524/recovering-data-points-from-an-image).
But there are some differences in my question.

I have this picture:

[image]

Now I can get the position of each white pixel

```
pic = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uBnQ.png"]

pos = pic // Thinning // PixelValuePositions[#, 1] &;


ListPlot[pos]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

My first thought was `FindFormula`.

But the result as you see is

```
In[22]:= FindFormula[pos]    
Out[22]= 143.798 &
```

If use the `FindFit`, what's the model should be try?

And can we fit it in the case of not knowing the model?

Comment: Why the close votes? It is clear what its been asked: The OP needs to find an analytical expression for the data collected from an image.

Comment: More luck may be had by translating the center of this to the origin and then thinking of some function in polar coordinates that could, perhaps, do this.

Comment: This might get you started: `pospol = {ArcTan[#1, #2], Norm[{#1, #2}]} & @@@ N[pos]` then `ListPlot[pospol]`. Note the periodic function which looks something like `a Abs[Sin[b x + c]]^d + e`, but also there is some drift in parameters

Comment: Forgot to mention, first you need to do `pos = (# - Mean@pos)&/@pos` to translate this to the origin. After all this and normalization I got the following plot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/TPQoH.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another approach that might be successful with some additional fine tuning.

```
pos = (pic = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uBnQ.png"]) // 
    Thinning // PixelValuePositions[#, 1] &;

center = Mean /@ Transpose[pos] // N;

out = Reap[
     Module[{nextPos = {pos[[690]]}, newList = pos, delta = {-1., 1.},
        lastPos = {pos[[690]]}},
      Do[
       {nextPos, newList} = 
        TakeDrop[newList, 
         First@Position[#, 
             First@MinimalBy[TakeSmallestBy[#, (Norm[#, 1] &), 5], (Norm[# + delta, 1] &)]] &
          [Transpose[newList] - First@nextPos // Transpose]];
       delta = (7*delta + 1*First[(lastPos - nextPos)] - 
           0.0039*First[({center} - lastPos)])/8.0039;
       lastPos = Sow[nextPos];,
       {866}
       ]
      ]][[2, 1]] ~Flatten~ 1;
```

One can use

```
Manipulate[
 Show[{ListPlot[out[[;; n]], PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 12}], 
   ListPlot[pos, PlotStyle -> Red]}, AspectRatio -> 1],
 {n, 2, Length@out, 1}]
```

to explore the creation of `out`.

Trying to find an analytical function using [`FindFormula`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindFormula.html)

```
formula = 
 FindFormula[#, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
    SpecificityGoal -> "Low", TargetFunctions -> {Sin, Cos, Power, Plus, Times}] & /@ 
  Transpose[out]
```

Plotting the results in comparison to the original data.

```
Show[{ListPlot[out, PlotStyle -> Gray, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 7}],
   ListPlot[pos, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 3}],
  ParametricPlot[Through[formula[p]], {p, 1, Length@pos}, 
   PlotStyle -> Hue[0.6]]},
 AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

```
Show[pic, %]
```

[image]

```
Show[ListPlot[Transpose@out], 
 Plot[Evaluate@Through[formula[x]], {x, 1, 1580}]]
```

[image]

```
ListPlot[{Reverse@out[[All, 1]], out[[All, 2]]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Not so much of an answer, but an extended comment, but I think I have it very nearly nailed:

```
pos2 = (# - Mean@pos & /@ (N@pos)) // #/Mean@(Norm /@ #) &
    Manipulate[
 Show[ListPlot[Reverse /@ pos2], 
  PolarPlot[Sqrt[a b]/Sqrt[
   a^2 Cos[c x]^2 + b^2 Sin[c x]^2], {x, -4.1 \[Pi], 4.1 \[Pi]}, 
   PlotStyle -> Orange]], {a, 1, 15}, {b, 1, 15}, {c, 1, 2}]
```

[image]

The expression under `PolarPlot` is the expression for an ellipse in polar coordinates relative to the center, except instead of `x` I have `c x` there so an error in phase accumulates just like can be seen in the data.

Comment: Thanks for your help.But find `Sqrt[a b]/Sqrt[a^2 Cos[c x]^2 + b^2 Sin[c x]^2]` is too hard for me.T_T