# How to reconstruct a given schematic picture from color image

Tags: plotting, image-processing

There is a nice website on popular Economics with stylish picture.

```
Import["http://www.economistsdoitwithmodels.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/06/ediwm_3_5x5postcardfront_outlines-400x280.jpg"]
```

I'm not that experienced in image recognition, so I wonder if there is a simple way to reconstruct the picture in `Mathematica`.

[image]

It would be nice to have all lines as separate list (of functions).

Text on the picture is not necessary. Accurate color rendering is not important. Scale may be larger.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: We'd love to help, but what have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @MarcoB, I've stuck at the very begining, as I can only imagine how to draw it in image editor. Most methods as `Binarize` give something, that I cannot proceed. May be just a tip, which function to use to separete lines by colors and covert them to lists of data.

Comment: Related: [recovering-data-points-from-an-image](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1524/recovering-data-points-from-an-image)

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries, I saw that post but what if lines closely intertwined. I mean, how to split the image to apply technique, suggested in the related question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Separating the lines can be done using `DominantColors`. The following is almost a straight copy from the documentation:

```
res = DominantColors[img, 25, {"CoverageImage", "Color"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Multicolumn[ImageMultiply @@@ res, Appearance -> "Horizontal"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

After this (and perhaps after using somewhat more dominant colors, 50 or so, and playing with the `MinColorDistance` option, setting it to 0 or close to 0) you can use the methods in the Q&A I referenced in the comment above.

Comment: @garej btw, if you may also be interested in using [this](http://blog.wolframalpha.com/2013/05/17/making-formulas-for-everything-from-pi-to-the-pink-panther-to-sir-isaac-newton/)

Comment: @egwenesedai, that is funny, I'll take a look.