# Finding position of text returned with TextRecognize

Tags: image-processing, ocr

I am trying to extract data from images (using some of the methods presented in [[1524]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1524/recovering-data-points-from-an-image)), and would like to have a way to selectively cover/remove text from axes and legends.

`TextRecognize` has been reasonably good at finding the text, but I am curious: is there a way to determine where this text is located?

For example, how could we determine the approximate image location of the "Test plot" text in the following case?

```
testImage = Image[Plot[x, {x, 0, 6 π}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Test plot", BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 24}]]
TextRecognize[testImage]
```

> [image]
>
> ```
> "Test plot  
> 5 10 15"
> ```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With enhanced in version 11.1 `TextRecognize` finding positions of recognized text becomes straightforward:

```
testImage = 
  Image[Plot[x, {x, 0, 6 π}, PlotLabel -> "Test plot", BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 24}]];
res = TextRecognize[testImage, "Block", "BoundingBox", RecognitionPrior -> "SparseText"];
HighlightImage[testImage, {"Boundary", res}]
```

> [image: output]

The original question is answered. But as one can see, not every glyph is recognized...

Another route goes through `ComponentMeasurements`:

```
comp = ComponentMeasurements[testImage, "BoundingBox"][[;; , 2]];
(* A workaround for bug *)
comp = Developer`FromPackedArray@comp;
comp = Rectangle @@@ comp;
comp = Select[comp, Area[#] < 10000 &];
HighlightImage[testImage, {"Boundary", comp}]
```

> [image: graphics]

Now every glyph is found. Voilà!