# How to improve the recognition quality when TextRecognize work on single character

Tags: bugs, image-processing, ocr

**Bug introduced in 11.0 and persisting through 11.3**

---

From [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/140460/21532), I doubt the capability to work on single character. So I give some test to verify this possibility. You can get my test `imgs` by this code

```
imgs = Binarize[
    Import[#]] & /@ {"https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvuFe.png", 
   "https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXHyv.png", 
   "https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Uxpo.png"};
```

Note the `TextRecognize[#, "Character"] & /@ imgs` will get nothing. We can get a example from the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TextRecognize.html) in **Examples/Applications**, that indicate the appropriate mask maybe can improve the performance to get a character, but I don't very like this method. Because it is hard to build a mask for characters `"i"`,`"j"` like
[image]

```
TextRecognize[#, 
   Masking -> MorphologicalTransform[#, "BoundingBoxes", Infinity], 
   RecognitionPrior -> "Character"] & /@ imgs
```

> `{{H,1,O},{m,Y},{d,d}}`

## Question

- Any **workaround** that can improve the recognition quality when `TextRecognize` work on single character

#### Or

- If we want to improve the recognition quality by **mask**, how to build correct mask?

I desire to make my [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/140407/21532) better by `TextRecognize`.

Comment: I recommend you putting your test images on http://imgur.com/, that those who use *Mathematica* version lower than 10 could work with them too.

Comment: `TextRecognize[#, "Character"] &` is not recognized syntax, as indicated by the stream of errors it generates. Furthermore, there is no indication in the documentation of that usage. Why do you suppose that it should work?

Comment: @MarcoB I'm in 11.1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I felt that I miss some simple way to unite closely located components and finally I found it: `ImageForestingComponents` (thanks to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18971/280) answer)!

- <sub>It is unfortunate that a link to this function isn't included in the "See Also" drop-down list neither on the Docs page for `ComponentMeasurements`, nor `MorphologicalComponents`, nor `MorphologicalTransform`. That's why I wasn't able to find it quickly...</sub>

I'll show how it can be used on the most problematic case with letter "i" which is formed by two not connected clusters of points:

```
i = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvuFe.png"]
```

> [image]

With horizontal radius `1` and vertical radius `6` we get a segmentation where our letter "i" is counted as a single component:

```
ImageForestingComponents[i, Automatic, {1, 6}] // Colorize
```

> [image]

Using `ComponentMeasurements` we can get the bounding boxes of our characters dropping the background:

```
c = ComponentMeasurements[ImageForestingComponents[i, Automatic, {1, 6}], 
  "BoundingBox", #"ConvexCoverage" < .9 &]
```

> ```
> {2 -> {{66., 125.}, {79., 161.}}, 3 -> {{46., 61.}, {84., 98.}}}
> ```

```
HighlightImage[i, {Yellow, Rectangle @@@ c[[All, 2]]}]
```

> [image]

`TextRecognize` accepts a set of `Rectangle` primitives as a `Mask` (it is documented under the `Examples ► Options ► Masking` sub-subsection):

```
TextRecognize[i, Masking -> Rectangle @@@ c[[All, 2]], RecognitionPrior -> "Character"]
```

> ```
> {"i", "O"}
> ```

That's all. :^)

Comment: And do you think this is a bug behavior on `TextRecognize` that cannot correctly recognize single character?

Comment: @yode When you give an improper mask to `TextRecognize` it is expected that it won't be able to recognize the character correctly.

Comment: I mean that case when we don't give any mask.Just `TextRecognize[img, "Character"]`

Comment: @yode `RecognitionPrior -> "Character"` assumes that we have only one character on the image (or on each masked area). And `TextRecognize` correctly recognizes the character "i" when it is the only char on the image: `TextRecognize[ImageTake[i, 80], RecognitionPrior -> "Character"]`.

Comment: I do not mean use `TextRecognize[i, RecognitionPrior -> "Character"]`(and I know what you have say in [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/140639/how-to-improve-the-recognition-quality-when-textrecognize-work-on-single-charact/141047?noredirect=1#comment381193_141047)).I just think `TextRecognize[i, "Character"]` should give a correct result.

Comment: See [this](https://ooo.0o0.ooo/2017/03/27/58d8f0019662d.jpg) please.

Comment: @yode Sorry, I forgot that `"Character"` also may be a *level* specification. The fact that `TextRecognize[i, "Character"]` and even `TextRecognize[i, "Character", RecognitionPrior -> "SparseText"]` do not return any result *may* indicate a bug either on the WRI side or on the side of the developers of [Tesseract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesseract_(software)) (upon which `TextRecognize` is based). You can check the latter on Windows using, for example, [gImageReader](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gimagereader/).

Comment: @yode I've checked gImageReader and it recognizes [`i`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvuFe.png) without difficulties. Given that I suspect that we indeed have a bug on the WRI side. I think it is worth to ask the tech support about this (also it is interesting which version of Tesseract is included in *Mathematica*).

Comment: Since this,I will report it to WRI right now..

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Dilation` with rectangular kernel to extend the bounding boxes vertically in order to connect closely related components:

```
MorphologicalTransform[#, "BoundingBoxes", Infinity] & /@ imgs
Dilation[#, Table[1, {6}, {1}]] & /@ %
```

> [image: screenshot]

With this approach

```
TextRecognize[#, 
   Masking -> Dilation[MorphologicalTransform[#, "BoundingBoxes", Infinity], 
     Table[1, {6}, {1}]], RecognitionPrior -> "Character"] & /@ imgs
```

> ```
> {{"i", "O"}, {"m", "Y"}, {"d", "d"}}
> ```

---

Use `ImageFilter` to connect only closely located bounding boxes:

```
uniteBoxes[image_, range_: 6] := 
 ImageFilter[If[#[[{1, -1}, 1]] == {1, 1}, 1, #[[Ceiling[Length[#]/2], 1]]] &, 
  image, {range {1, 1}, {0, 0}}]

uniteBoxes@MorphologicalTransform[#, "BoundingBoxes", Infinity] & /@ imgs

TextRecognize[#, 
   Masking -> uniteBoxes[MorphologicalTransform[#, "BoundingBoxes", Infinity]], 
   RecognitionPrior -> "Character"] & /@ imgs
```

> [image: output]
>
> ```
> {{"i", "O"}, {"m", "Y"}, {"d", "d"}}
> ```

---

More robust approach:

```
fillGaps[list_, length_: 6] := 
  ReplacePart[list, 
   List /@ Flatten[Range @@@ SequencePosition[list, {1, Repeated[0, {1, length}], 1}]] -> 
    1];
connectVertically[image_, distance_: 6] := 
 Image[Transpose[fillGaps[#, distance] & /@ Transpose[ImageData[image]]]]
connectVertically@MorphologicalTransform[#, "BoundingBoxes", Infinity] & /@ imgs
```

> [image: output]

---

P.S. It is possible that approaches shown in the following threads can be used to speed-up searching for closely located components (knowing the coordinates of their bounding boxes):

- [How to connect some separate components with shortest total length line](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/118132/280)
- [How to rapidly find the nearest pairs of points in different clusters](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/138043/280)

Also, `DistanceMatrix` can be of use here.

Comment: The `Dilation` will enlager all mask, though the character is not `i` or `j`

Comment: @yode I updated the answer with an approach that affects only closely located components.

Comment: Thanks for your update,I need some time to through it...