# How to find all number in a image by neural-networks method

Tags: image-processing, neural-networks

I have a big complaint about function `TextRecognize`. [Alexey Popkov](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/280/alexey-popkov) have verified [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/140639/how-to-improve-the-recognition-quality-when-textrecognize-work-on-single-charact#comment381203_141047). Actually it can do it as the attribute `"BoundingBox"` if the function is normally.

```
HighlightImage[ColorNegate[Binarize[img1]], 
 TextRecognize[img1, "Word", "BoundingBox"]]
```

[image]

But as you see,it will give a very bad result.Since the *MMA* have the function of neural-networks,so I want to expect a neural-networks method to **find all number and the position of the number**. I have some samples image here for test

```
img1=Uncompress[FromCharacterCode[
  Flatten[ImageData[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/keYUf.png"],"Byte"]]]]

img2 = Uncompress[FromCharacterCode[
   Flatten[ImageData[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/U86l9.png"],"Byte"]]]]

img3=Uncompress[FromCharacterCode[
  Flatten[ImageData[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/V76u5.png"],"Byte"]]]]
```

Could anyone can give some advice?

Comment: I think a traditional method may be easier. For example, use something like `ContourDetect[img1]` to detect the position of the numbers and characters, and then crop out the numbers and characters and feed them into a classifier.

Comment: @xslittlegrass Sorry, the processed image alway is gray image. and I cannot ensure the line of the frame will be more black than the digtal.So I have edited that original image just now..