# Detection the coordinates of all points of a curve on an image file

Tags: plotting, image-processing, education

I have a plot of a curve (the black curve without dashes) on an image file.jpg:

[image]

http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=48857135704766357735

I'd like to detect the coordinates of all point of the curve. Is it possible to do it with Mathematica?

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: related:  [Recovering data points from an image](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1524/125)

Comment: @kglr thank you very much for your tip.